# Port using current bash terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

I am not able to fire up one ofthe docker containers using

```
docker-compose up
```

because bind for port 0.0.0.0:8081 is already allocated.

figuring what it is

```
ps -ef | grep :8081
```

gives

```
info     21840 21758  0 21:04 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto :8081
```

and killing it shuts down the current bash terminal.
 whats going on? I dont want that port to be used? And how is it linked to any current bash terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Your command "ps" gives as result the pid of "grep" command itself.

What you are looking for is "netstat -anp", whom gives the list of ports and owner pid's.

Comment: nv mind. there was a service started by root. restarting machine worked.